# Strange SQL generated by Linq2SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a linq query that looks as follows: (part of a bigger query but this demonstrates the problem)

```
from guarantee in tblGuarantees
from nextExptDev in
            (from gd in tblGuaranteeDevaluations
             where gd.fkGuaranteeId == guarantee.pkGuaranteeId &&
                   gd.Date == null
             orderby gd.ExpectedDate ascending
             select new
             {
                gd.Sum,
                gd.CurrencyId,
                gd.ExpectedDate
             }).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    guarantee.pkGuaranteeId,
    nextExptDev.Sum,
    nextExptDev.CurrencyId,
    nextExptDev.ExpectedDate
}
```

It generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[pkGuaranteeId],
       [t3].[Sum]          AS [Sum],
       [t3].[CurrencyId]   AS [CurrencyId],
       [t3].[ExpectedDate] AS [ExpectedDate2]
FROM   [dbo].[tblGuarantee] AS [t0]
       CROSS APPLY ((SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]) AS [t1]
                    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[Sum],
                                                [t2].[CurrencyId],
                                                [t2].[ExpectedDate]
                                 FROM   [dbo].[tblGuaranteeDevaluation] AS [t2]
                                 WHERE  ( [t2].[fkGuaranteeId] = [t0].[pkGuaranteeId] )
                                        AND ( [t2].[Date] IS NULL )
                                 ORDER  BY [t2].[ExpectedDate]) AS [t3])
ORDER  BY [t3].[ExpectedDate] -- Why here?
```

My question is, why is that last `ORDER BY` there? In my bigger query that really hurts performance and I cant figure out why it is needed.
Also any hint on writing this in a better way is appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you switch the `DefaultIfEmpty()` with the `Take(1)` call? What about replacing both with just a `FirstOrDefault` call? What about just using `let nextExptDev = ...` instead of `from nextExptDev in ...`?

Comment: @SPFiredrake All good suggestions that I have tried. Removing the `DefaultIfEmpty()` will not remove the outer `ORDER  BY` (also it will not generate the same result set). Using the `let..` was my first choice but that generates one left join to the inner query for every property in the select (4 in this case) so that is even worse. Doing just `FirstOrDefault` will only work with the let solution.

Comment: Try one last thing for me... It seems that putting the `order by` within the transformation is conveying to the rest of the query that you want the whole thing ordered by that. Instead, see if you can just select it from the ordered source. IE: `from gd in tblGuaranteeDevaluations.OrderBy(t => t.ExpectedDate)`.

Answer (score 2):

In the query you are doing a order by in the

```
from gd in tblGuaranteeDevaluations
         where gd.fkGuaranteeId == guarantee.pkGuaranteeId &&
               gd.Date == null
         orderby gd.ExpectedDate ascending
```

This made the inner query do the order by, in the inner block

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[Sum], [t2].[CurrencyId], [t2].[ExpectedDate]
    FROM [dbo].[tblGuaranteeDevaluation] AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t2].[fkGuaranteeId] = [t0].[pkGuaranteeId]) AND ([t2].[Date] IS NULL)
    ORDER BY [t2].[ExpectedDate]
```

But you are "joining" 2 different sets, the null set and the inner block set, for that, to ensure the order, the code have to put another **order by**, for the result set of the "join", so that why the order is in the outer set, is automatic code generation, but because the set is already ordered, the last **order by** should not degrade performance.

Comment: I still don't get it. If I remove the last order by I get the same result (unordered) as I do with it. Also if I remove the "null set", (remove the `.DefaultIfEmpty()`) it still generates the order by.

Comment: The unorder or order result is from the sql engine, and may return the same result, or may not. In the other hand it still generate the **order by** because is automatic code generation.

Comment: Obviously the `order by` is automatic code generation. But the question is why. There is not reason for it to be there, and I don't want the result set to be ordered. I don't feel that your answer gives any clarity.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you switch the `DefaultIfEmpty()` with the `Take(1)` call? What about replacing both with just a `FirstOrDefault` call? What about just using `let nextExptDev = ...` instead of `from nextExptDev in ...`?

Try one last thing for me... It seems that putting the `order by` within the projection is conveying to the rest of the query that you want the whole thing ordered by that. Instead, see if you can just select it from the ordered source. IE: `from gd in tblGuaranteeDevaluations.OrderBy(t => t.ExpectedDate)`.

Comment: Tried `from gd in tblGuaranteeDevaluations.OrderBy(t => ...` as you suggested, but unfortunately that generates the same SQL.

Comment: @Magnus Not sure what to tell you. I tried performing a similar query on a local DB, and didn't seem to like it either. For some reason, it just doesn't want to perform the `CROSS APPLY` on a top 1 without ordering the outer query as well (which is most definitely the wrong behavior). Good luck, I'll keep an eye out and see if I come across anything that could help.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll add an answer if I'm able to resolve it myself.

Answer (score -1):

in your query you're doing this:

`orderby gd.ExpectedDate ascending` and that is reflected in the SQL generated.

Comment: But that should only generate an inner order by, what is the outer one doing there?